# How to use BufferedWriter in socket communication in java?

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I am trying to send a string through sockets but I just have some problems. the string that I am trying to send is ; (ATTENTION : It is a string NOT XML )

```
<message>
<header>
<messageType>snmp</messageType>
<sendFrom>192.168.0.16</sendFrom>
<hostName>oghmasysMehmet</hostName>
<sendTo>192.168.0.12</sendTo>
<receiverName>Mehmet</receiverName>
<date>03/10/2011</date>
</header>
<body>
<snmpType>getbulk</snmpType>
<ip>127.0.0.1</ip>
<port>161</port>
<oids>
  <oid>1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0</oid>
</oids>
<community>community</community>
<nR>0</nR>
<mR>5</mR>
</body>
</message>
```

But when I look what I get from server it is just ;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

I dont know what is the problem:

I am using ,

```
socket = new Socket(localIP, Integer.parseInt(localPort));
out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
```

to send the string from client and use,

```
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
line = in.readLine();
```

to read the string on server.

Can you please help me how I can solve it ?

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucas has the answer, I believe.  Personally, I don't trust readLine() as in doing so is making the assumption that you are recv-ing valid String data on the socket.... which is a very poor assumption!

Try reading into a byte buffer first, then try to make it into a string:

```
byte[] buf = new byte[4096];

int actualNumberOfBytesRead = socket.getInputStream().read(buf);

String dataString = new String(buf, 0, actualNumberOfBytesRead);
```

...Now, my example has a few issues to it, but the point (should) be made =D

Answer (score 1):

Could be a missing newline character as BufferedReader.readLine will not return until a new line character is available on the stream.

Answer (score 1):

Well you've written out some XML which contains more than a single line. The first line is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

On the server you've then read the first line - you've got one `readLine()` call. Unsurprisingly, that's giving you a single line of text.

If you want to send a string including line breaks as a single line, you'll need to escape those line breaks.

A nicer alternative is not to rely on lines at all: length prefix each string you send, so you send:

- Length (in bytes) as 4 bytes
- String data (as a byte array)

On the reading side, you'd read 4 bytes to find out how long the message is, then read the message into a byte array, then construct the string from that byte array.

`DataInputStream` and `DataOutputStream` can help you do that reasonably simply. Note that you should definitely specify the encoding you use for all strings; UTF-8 is a good starting point in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be looping over in.readline until no further input available.

Check example on the http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/readingWriting.html

Answer (score 0):

First of all: You should really be using a buffer to parse whatever the server sent to you. See http://www.kodejava.org/examples/266.html for a good example.

If you hate adding this to your code, you can use the Apache Commons IO library to do the following:

```
ByteArrayInputStream out = new ByteArrayInputStream();
IOUtils.readFully( in, out );
String output = new String( out.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
```

Please note you should take care to flush() the stream server-side. Let the client close the socket as soon as all data is received. This way, you cannot close() the socket too early.